# Importing a local file as a module in Akshell

Tags: javascript, module

Does anyone have a working example of importing a local file as a module in [Akshell](http://akshell.com)?

I've uploaded [DOMBuilder.js](https://github.com/insin/DOMBuilder/blob/master/DOMBuilder.js) to my Akshell app, which according to the [documentation](http://www.akshell.com/docs/0.3/ref/basic/modules/) should be compatible with the way Akshell's modules work, but I just get an empty Object back when I use `require('./DOMBuilder')` in the Eval shell, while attempting to use it in a view function or template just gives me "Internal Application Error" with no stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jonathan, I've ported your library to Akshell 0.2: [DOMBuilder.js](https://github.com/akshell/form/blob/master/DOMBuilder.js). In Akshell 0.3 you should just use `require('ak')` as a first line.

The main problem was in the line 970:

```
module.exports = DOMBuilder;
```

You can't substitute the `exports` object, you should put properties on it.

Comment: Thanks, that works. Different behaviour from Node.js, so that's one in the eye for the "same code everywhere" dream :) Here's a gist which demonstrates current behaviour: https://gist.github.com/881067